# terminator selective history

Tags: terminator

When I scroll through the command line history in terminator, (with the  &  arrows), I always get at the last inserted command. I would like to get only the commands that begin with `cp` ,for example, when I have already typed `cp` and pressed the uparrow.

Comment: Simplest way seems to be strip .bash_history (assuming you're using bash) to remove all the history except commands starting with 'cp'.

Comment: not an answer but... do you know ctrl+R for incremental reverse history search? press ctrl+R and type `cp`...

Comment: I want to have it very simple like it worked on another terminal before (dont know exactly which one, guess it was the standard one on Mint XFCE). There I could type the first letters of any command and then it only showed this specific commands when scrolling through history. that is a very logical feature